# Get the table name is returned by a sql query in application

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns a table. But it can return two kind of tables according to what condition it has like below

```
...

if @TestCondition > 0 
        begin 
            select  *
            from    Test1 NoExpiredTable
        end
    else 
        begin 
            select  *
            from    Test2 ExpiredTable
        end
```

So in the application how can I get the table name ? What I tried is

```
 if (ds.Tables[0].TableName == "NoExpiredTable")
 {

 }
```

but ds.Tables[0].TableName gives me "Table".

Comment: In addition to the table result, consider providing an output parameter e.g. `@is_expired CHAR(1)` set by the proc to either `'T'` or `'F'` as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

SQL queries do not return tables. They return result sets. A result set has no name.

Answer (score 3):

The result set has no concept of the table it came from, you can include the table name in the records returned by the procedure . . .

```
if @TestCondition > 0 
    begin 
        select  *, 'NoExpiredTable' TableName
        from    Test1 NoExpiredTable
    end
else 
    begin 
        select  *, 'ExpiredTable' TableName
        from    Test2 ExpiredTable
    end
```

Then you can access it the same way you'd access any other column.

This won't do anything for you if no rows are returned, you won't know which table was selected from.

Here you can return a single record with the result of the condition (i.e. a single row with a single column, TableName) then the records from the actual table. e.g.

select case when

```
if @TestCondition > 0 
    begin 
        select 'NoExpiredTable' TableName

        select  *
        from    Test1 NoExpiredTable
    end
else 
    begin 
        select 'ExpiredTable' TableName

        select  *
        from    Test2 ExpiredTable
    end
```

Comment: I tried both way you advised but they didnt work. ds.Tables[0].TableName keeps giving me "Table" as the name. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Ryu: I couldn't even guess without knowing how you're calling the stored procedure and what data you have. When you execute the - second - procedure directly (in QueryAnalyser) do you get both result sets? Also when using the first method, `ds.Tables[0].TableName` will never work, you'll need to access the TableName column e.g. something like `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TableName"]` I'm guessing the syntax to get the column, I've never used datasets.